# MATLAB: How to extract specific columns from a csv file?

Tags: matlab, csv

I have to extract 1, 2, and 4 th column from a given csv file and write it to a new file. It is important that the new file contains 1, 2, and 4th column from original file in 1, 2, 3rd column in new file.

I know the first step would be to extract the required values in an array:

```
CSVOutput = csvread(‘NumericData.csv’, startx, starty, [startx, starty, endx, endy])
```

then I can use `csvwrite` to put this is a new file.

But the problem is I do not know the `endx, endy`. I can only manually check it.

So is there any more elegant way ?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? Perhaps you could use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html "Create table from file") instead of `csvread`. Also, the last input in `csvread` is optional, I'd just ignore it and delete the first lines of the imported data to get the same effect as specifying `startx`, `starty`.

Comment: @Dev-iL my version r2014a

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
t = readtable(file.csv);
```

as Dev-iL suggested. The returned object is a struct, where each field is named after a column of the table. With

```
fieldnames(t);
```

you get a cell array containing the names of the colums.

You can access a column as follows:

```
t.('columnName')
```